# java: double == and Double equals

Tags: java, double

I am confused on a few things regarding using double.

1. If i were to initialize 2 doubles with the same literal, would == always evaluate to true? for example, if following outputs true but i don't know if this is by chance:

   ```
   double a = .1d;
   double b = .1d;
   System.out.println(a==b);
   ```
2. I get the same result when using Double instead of double:

   ```
   Double a = .1d;
   Double b = .1d;
   System.out.println(a.equals(b));
   ```

According to Double documentation, equals() return true if doubleValue() are equal.

So the question is, is "==" for double and "equals()" for Double guaranteed to evaluate to true for 2 variables initialized using the same literal?

When would they evaluate to false? Is this when arithmetic operations are involved?

Thanks

Comment: when do they evaluate false... when the values are different.

Comment: It follows the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: In the first example, why do you think `a` and `b` might _not_ be equal? Floating points are a bit wonky with their rounding rules, sure, but they're not magic -- and they are deterministic. What do you think might happen between `a` and `b` that would give them different values?

Comment: double has something to do with precision and follows IEEE 754 standards.

Comment: Note that when a double variable contains NaN, it won't be equals to itself, let alone to another variable. Strictly speaking though, you can't assign NaN to a variable with a single literal. You'd need two, such as `double d = 0.0/0.0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `==` is an operator which checks for equality. Object variables are references so it checks for reference or address equality. In the case of primitive data types representing values in the memory that also means that it checks for value equality.

The method `equals(~)` checks for value or content equality. You do not use it for primitive data types but for Objects.

That is also the case for double and Double. The problem which is arising with doubles is the mismatch of the values induced by rounding errors.

Some arithmetic operations may handle rounding differently so you might get `false` for value equality even if you think it should be equal.

It should be stated that even if the rounding rules are a bit inconsistent arithmetic operations are deterministic so that inconsistency can be handled.

Comment: Cross-platform, floating point arithmetic is not always deterministic. To enforce equivalence, one should use the `StrictMath` class instead of the `Math` class. Although I haven't yet seen such inconsistency, it can arise when e.g. on an x86 machine internal floating point operations are done in 80-bit mode, and the result stored in a 64-bit double. Other architectures than x86 don't have an 80-bit mode.